# Javascript RegExp Allow Spaces Inside Pattern

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I need to replace all `"*text*"` into `"<strong>text</strong>"`

when passing text = `"normal text *words to be bolded* continue normal text"` it doesn't work because of the spaces, it works only for single-word text.

wanted result: `"normal text <strong>words to be bolded</strong> continue normal text"`

result: `"normal text *words to be bolded* continue normal text"`

I need this function to work for whatever the text is:

```
function bold(text){
    reg = /\*(\w+)\*/g
    return text.replaceAll(reg, "<strong>" + text.split(reg)[1] + "</strong>")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allow a set of characters to be there. Right now, you have the sequence of characters fixed.

```
function bold(text){
    reg = /\*([\w\s]+)\*/g
    return text.replaceAll(reg, "<strong>" + text.split(reg)[1] + "</strong>")
}
```

Comment: This will prevent characters like `!` and `?` from being included, though.

Comment: Yeah, right. I didn't answer the full requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array split method.

```js
const str = "word1 word2 pla pla";
const newStr = [];
str.split(" ").forEach((val) => {
  newStr.push(`<strong>${val}</strong> `);
});
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Yes I do agree, I'm afraid that's not the case here, while those words may be contained/embedded  inside a wider string

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by 'words to be bolded', you are trying to match anything that is not asterisk.

```js
function bold(text){
    let reg = /\*([^\*]*)\*/g;
    return text.replaceAll(reg, "<strong>$1</strong>")
};
let result = bold("normal1 *bold1 including space!* normal2 *bold2, including space?* normal3"); 
console.log(result);
```